# Permission error with PHP 8 and Session Handler

Tags: php, node.js

Dears, I`m refracting old php code 4 to php 8, but I'm having some errors on Session Control. I implementing a SessionHandlerInterface, but I still having error when execute session write

**Warning**:  file_put_contents(../sessions/sess_fc6a0b26f218654ca0f45493861fdf58): failed to open stream: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente in **/home/pedro/htdocs/ypanel/session.controller.php** on line **36**

**Warning**:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: ../sessions) in **Unknown** on line **0**

I'm using Lampp with Mysql on Debian.

Here my class

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//=========================================================================================
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
//=========================================================================================
session_save_path("../sessions");
//=========================================================================================
error_reporting(2);
//=========================================================================================
class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    private $savePath;

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        // printf(file_exists($savePath));
        // printf(is_dir($this->savePath).' dir');
        $this->savePath = $savePath;
        if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) 
        {
            chmod($this->savePath,0777);
            mkdir($this->savePath, 0777,true);
        }
        else printf('diretorio ja existe'); 
        return true;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        return (string)@file_get_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id");
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        return file_put_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id", $data) === false ? false : true;
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $file = "$this->savePath/sess_$id";
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        foreach (glob("$this->savePath/sess_*") as $file) {
            if (filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

    $handler = new MySessionHandler();
    session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
    session_start();

    

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using both `session_save_path` and `ini_set('session.save_path'`? Regardless, make sure that you set them exactly the same, that the folder exists or you have permission to create it, and that you have permission to write to that folder. Since you're going from 4 to 8, I assume that your server changed, too, so permissions might not be what you expected either

Comment: I solved the problema i get the root path  plus the folder now  it stop error.

Comment: One doubt I have one class named httpd.post.php,  how to inport using namescapes

Comment: You have a class with periods in the name? Or a file? As far as I know, [even in PHP 4 you couldn't have a class with periods in the name](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php4/en/language.oop5.basic).